# Memory usage in Azure Monitoring does not match what is reported in Availability and Performance

Tags: azure, memory, memory-management, devops, azure-container-apps

Hi I am new to devops.

Attached are two screenshots taken of the same Azure container app resource at the same time and with the same 24hour time period. My local computer is set to UTC.

The first screenshot is what I see if from the Container App home, I click `Diagnose and solve problems` > `Availability and Performance` > `Container App Memory Usage` It shows I reached a high of 885MB and  triggers the 70% high usage warning
[image: Availability and performance]

The second screenshot is what I see if I click `Overview` > `Monitoring` > `Memory Working Set Bytes`. At no point does it go above 600MB in the same last 24 hours
[image: Azure Monitoring]

Can someone please explain this to me? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory usage metrics of the same Azure container app are shown in two screenshots, but they have different maximum values, which creates confusion.

Here are the reasons for the discrepancy:

1. **Different Metrics**: A possible reason for the discrepancy between the two screenshots is that they are measuring different aspects of memory usage. The first screenshot could be displaying the average value of a metric that accumulates data over time, while the second screenshot could be showing the peak value of the working set bytes.
2. **Sampling Intervals**: A possible reason for the discrepancy in the tools' results is that they sample the memory usage at different intervals. This can affect how they capture the variations in memory consumption over time.
   .
3. **Aggregation Over Time**: One possible tool is to aggregate data over a longer period, such as an hour's average, and another is to display data that is more current or has a shorter aggregation time.
4. **Metric Definitions**: The tools may have different definitions or methods of measuring memory. For instance, some may account for more memory types than others in their measurement.
5. **Time Zone Differences**: Even though your local computer is set to UTC, the tools might be using different time zone settings internally which could affect how the data is aligned and displayed.

To resolve this issue:

- Ensure both metrics are intended to measure the same thing (e.g., total memory usage vs. working set).
- Check the documentation for both monitoring tools to understand exactly what they're measuring and how they aggregate data.

**reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/metrics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/supported-metrics/microsoft-app-containerapps-metrics